# main Methods in c++ in different class files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In Java, you can have each class hold it's own main method, but when I tried to create two cpp files in C++, both with their own main methods, the compiler told me that main was already defined. Does that mean I need a new project for each main method? I am following a C++ tutorial, and I don't want to have to create a new project for every example program we do, I just want one project with multiple main methods. Is this possible?

Comment: There is no concept of "project" in C++. You need a `main()` for each executable. That's about it.

Comment: This is more ide-specific. Please let us know what ide you are using.

Comment: Is a project a "solution" then? In visual studio, that's what it calls them, I have no idea if this is a convention or not...

Comment: @JesseGood I'm using visual studio 2010

Comment: @opiop65 In Visual Studio, a "project" is a container for code which will be compiled and linked into a single module (e.g. executable, static library, or dynamic library). A "solution" is a container for a set of "projects" which you want to keep together, presumably because they are related (e.g. you might have a project for your core code which compiles to a static library, and a separate project with your GUI code which links to the static library, but builds to an executable).

Comment: Why would you want two main functions anyway? You don't need a program class like in Java.

Comment: When you say "I just want one project with multiple main methods", it seems to me (not sure though) that you are confounding "projects", which are a construct of Visual Studio, and "executables".  An executable can have only one "main" entry point.  Do you want one _executable_, and the ability to run different routines within that executable, or do you want multiple executables?  If the latter, then you will need multiple projects within one "solution".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.cpp` don't have "methods", probably what you defined are free functions (i.e. procedures not bound to any class), and they are all in the same namespace. This of course gives errors at the linking stage, since you are multiply defining the same thing.

If you want to define a class, you can use the `class` keyword; of course in that case, as in Java, every class you define can have its own `main` method.

> I am following a C++ tutorial, and I don't want to have to create a new project for every example program we do, I just want one project with multiple main methods. Is this possible?

No. The entrypoint is just one - the global `main` function. If you want to allow for several possible "subprograms", write each one of them in a separate function, and decide which one to call from the single `main`.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. In Java you can have one project with multiple main functions, but C++ doesn't work that way at all?

Answer (score 1):

In `C#`, each project has its own `Program.cs` file, which is the entry point. If you end up combining multiple projects, it's trivial to tell Visual Studio to compile it as a library, and choose which project's entry point to use.

In `C++`, you can only have one definition of `main` in the global namespace. You can for example, have your own custom main in a namespace which `::main` will call. This technique is done in SDL for example so that the user does not have to create a `main` himself, and he can link `-lSDL_main`.

Answer (score 0):

In MS Visual Studio, one "solution" (.sln file) will contain multiple "projects".  Each executable you want to produce will have its own "project", and you can have many such projects within the same "solution".  Not every "project" needs to produce an executable though - often a "project" will just produce a library, for example a library of common utilities that many of your executables may include.  When you put two "main()" projects into two .cpp files in the same project, the compiler will have compiled both .cpp files into .obj files, and then likely tried to create one executable with both .obj files linked in to the executable.  And you will get an error when the linker tries to put both "main()" functions into the same executable, since you cannot have two entry points with the same name.

What Matteo says about classes and methods is also something you must understand.

Comment: Ah, I see. So a solution can hold multiple "projects"? But a "project" cannot hold more than one class with a main method? I get it now, I think.

Comment: @opiop65 You haven't fully understood. The `main` function you are referring to (i.e. the entry point to an executable) does not live in a class. It is a free function declared in the global namespace. You can have as many classes as you want with functions called `main`, and they will be totally unrelated to each other, and unrelated to the entrypoint function, `main`. I think you are confused because you have come from Java. In C++, you do not need to have a class in order to have a function.

Comment: So how does the compiler pick the right "main" function then? My book has also told me what you just said, that I can have multiple functions with the identifier "main", but how does that work?

Comment: @opiop65 Because in C++, named items like functions live within enclosing structures such as classes and namespaces (which themselves live within the global namespace), and it is the fully qualified name which needs to be unique. For example, if you have a class called `Foo` which has a function called `main`, then that function's fully qualified name is `Foo::main`. C++ uses a function called `main` in the global namespace as it's entry point. `main` is different to `Foo::main` which is how the compiler can identify it.

Comment: What JBentley is saying is correct.  To put it differently: when linking a bunch of object files together to make an executable, there MUST be EXACTLY ONE "main(...)" that is in the "global" scope.  This is the entry point that the OS invokes when the executable is run.  Because all the object files produced within a "project" are placed together (and thus if a project is linked into an executable, they are all linked in), there can thus be only one global "main" in a project.

Comment: And to clarify JBentley's second comment: When items live within enclosing structures such as a namespace or class, it is the "fully qualified" name (and signature), i.e. "foo::main" which must be unique.  This is the same in Java.  The difference is that in C++, you have things (functions and variables) which can "live" or "be" in the "global" scope, i.e. not be "contained" within any other class or namespace structure.  Within this global scope, again named objects must be unique.  Also within this global scope, there must be exactly one "main(...)" function.

Comment: All languages do this behind the scenes, you are just not always aware of it.  In C++, the compiler doesn't look after nearly as many things for you.  This means, you have to understand better how things work.  So you have more control, but then also have more responsibility, and more ability to make mistakes.